# Delegate to Communicate between 2 UIViews in Swift

Tags: swift, delegates, ios-frameworks

I have two views as apart of a framework of mine:

1. `JSQRCodeScannerView` is a camera view
2. `JSQRCodeInstructionsView` is a smaller view that takes up about 40% of the bottom of the screen like in Apple Maps on iOS

Right now I am attempting to use a delegate to communicate between the two views. Specifically, when a scan is completed, I call a delegate method called `didScanSuccessfully()` and aim to use that delegate method in the `JSQRCodeInstructionsView` class to update its label.

`JSQRCodeScannerView`

```
protocol JSQRCodeScannerViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didScanQRCodeSuccessfully()
}

class JSQRCodeScannerView: UIView {

    weak var delegate: JSQRCodeScannerViewDelegate?


    func scanIsCompleted() {
        delegate?.didScanQRCodeSuccessfully()
    }

}
```

`JSQRCodeInstructionsView`

```
class JSQRCodeInstructionsView: UIView, JSQRCodeScannerViewDelegate {

      func didScanQRCodeSuccessfully() {
          //Update label
      }

}
```

Right now, I cannot get the delegate method in `JSQRCodeInstructionsView` to fire. Everything works up to that point. Am I missing a step or is there something wrong with communication between two UIViews in a framework specifically that won't work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the delegate is 'nil'.
Try setting the `JSQRCodeInstructionsView` as the delegate of `JSQRCodeScannerViewDelegate` somewhere, like so:

```swift
jsQRCodeScannerViewInstance.delegate = jsQRCodeInstructionsViewInstance
```